# jMeter stops intermittently when sending big amount of requests

Tags: java, jmeter

I set up 100 threads for sending 120000 requests per minute, and I have already adjusted the JVM arguments like:

```
-Xms2g -Xmx3g -Xss2m
```

My computer is tough enough to supply this resources, but still jMeter would stop intermittently when sending this level of number of requests. At first, I guessed it is GC which will stop the world when doing its jobs that leads to this problem, but now, I am not sure what is going on and how deal with it.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give more details on your issue and show plan and jmeter.log but some things to check:

- Are you using GUI mode to load test, if yes switch to Non GUI mode
- did you set timeouts, maybe it's your server which is slowing down, set timeouts to see if it's the case

Read this:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/

Answer (score 0):

120000 requests per minute stands for 2000 requests per second.

1. Are you sure that 100 concurrent threads can produce 2000 requests per second? If you run JMeter with 1 thread will it create 20 requests per second throughput?
2. How do you set the desired throughput? Do you use [Constant Throughput Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)? If not - try increasing number of threads and see how it goes.
3. Make sure that you use 64-bit JVM and run JMeter in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
4. 3 Gigabytes of heap space may not be enough. Try increasing heap to ~70% of your available physical RAM and disable swap file.